# Flutter , how to make the app looking similar in mobile and tablet (i.e eg we can use white spaces from left and right in tablet)

Tags: flutter, layout, responsive-design, tablet

I want my app to remain similar as it is in mobile . I want to add white spaces from left and right in tablet so that it doesnot create any mess and look similar to the mobile .
I have tried layout builder to do that but in that case i need to edit every screen and every class of my project  i am searching for something else which can be applied on one place only leading to add white space margins from left and right in the tablet so that the screen size remains same as to that of mobile .

Comment: use `Padding` widget: `Padding(child: MaterialApp(...), ...)`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.. but when you say: "...same as to that of mobile..". Which mobile with which resolution? And if you don't select the smallest screen size that your app can run on, what do you want to happen when a smaller size is used than the one you have as your "mobile" definition?

Comment: a mobile of 6.3 inches , i have handled all the cases for lower than this screen size but for tablets  i need help

Comment: for tablet , i want to use something like layout builder buddy

Comment: i need to apply layout builder at every place of my project and my project is very large in size i want something which i apply on one place and the change happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `LayoutBuilder`. The `MainContentWidget` is the main content widget. You render the main content widget if the screen width is less than 600 otherwise you specify the content width which by the sample code provided below is 60% of the screen then position it at the center.

```
Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth < 600) {
          return MainContentWidget();
        }

        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60,
            child: MainContentWidget(),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  )
```

Comment: i dont want to use layout builder anything else?

Comment: @VIADISHWARSHARMA That's what the Flutter team recommend for this use case.

Comment: can i do this in my main file?